# launch angle required for projectile to clear two walls

Tags: homework-and-exercises, velocity

a particle is projected with a velocity $\sqrt{4 g h}$ from the ground level so as to just clear two walls of the same height $h$ situated $2h$ from each other.

how can we show that the time of passing between the walls is $2\sqrt{\frac{h}{g}}$?

Answer (score 1):

1. Using conservation of energy, calculate the speed $u$ of the projectile when it reaches the top of the 1st wall. Now the problem is to find the time of flight between the walls when launch speed is $u$ and range is $2h$.
2. Express the horizontal and vertical components of velocity $u_x$ and $u_y$ in terms of time of flight $t$ and range $2h$ between the walls.
3. The components must satisfy $u_x^2+u_y^2=u^2$. Substitute for $u_x, u_y$ to get an equation for $t$.
4. The equation has $t^4$ as the highest power. It could be difficult to solve, but there is no need to do so. All you need to do is show by substitution that $t=2\sqrt{\frac{h}{g}}$ satisfies this equation.